# Use character string as function argument

Tags: string, r, function

I'm sure this is simple, but I cannot find a solution ...
I would like to use a variable containing a character string as argument for a function.

```
x <- c(1:10)
myoptions <- "trim=0, na.rm=FALSE"
```

Now, something like

```
foo <- mean(x, myoptions)
```

should be the same as

```
foo <- mean(x, trim=0, na.rm=FALSE)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Although I am sure someone will post a solution to this, I think doing this is a bit unusual.  Do you want to give a bit more background on what really you want to do?

Comment: I have a CSV file written by an external program which contains one string of arguments per line. This should be used as input for the svm() function to build SVM models with different settings. So the first line of the CSV file is "cost=1, gamma=0.001", the second line is "cost=5, gamma=0.001" and so on. I want to loop over all lines of the CSV file.

Comment: If you paste the first few line of the CSV file, probably you will get better answer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `eval` and `parse`:

```
foo <- eval(parse(text = paste("mean(x,", myoptions, ")")))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! Perhaps my thought were in the wrong direction -- so there is no way to do it in a way like `foo <- mean(x, take.this.as.arguments(myoptions))` ?

Comment: @Kilian it is difficult, maybe impossible.

Comment: I suspect that @koshke would no longer say this to be even difficult. I think that csgillespie's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 14):

A more natural way to do what you want is to use `do.call`. For example,

```
R> l[["trim"]] = 0
R> l[["na.rm"]] = FALSE
R> l[["x"]] = 1:10
##Or l <- list(trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, x = 1:10)
R> do.call(mean, l)
 [1] 5.5
```

If for some reason you really want to use a `myoptions` string, you could always use `strsplit` to coarce it into a list form. For example,

```
R> y = "trim=0, na.rm=FALSE"
R> strsplit(y, ", ")
[[1]]
[1] "trim=0"      "na.rm=FALSE" 
R> strsplit(y, ", ")[[1]][1]
[1] "trim=0"
```

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `l <- list(trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, x = 1:10)`?

Comment: I'm voting for the second method: `do.call` with `strsplit`.

Comment: @DWin Why do you prefer `do.call`/`strsplit` than `eval`/`parse`? I'm aware that some people don't like to use `eval`/`parse`. Is there any reason? Thanks.

Comment: I'm just trying to follow the of advice of the majority of my betters. Since I consider you to also be one of my betters, I admit to being conflicted.

Comment: I suspect at the end of the day,  `do.call` vs `parse` is sort of like vi vs emacs.  But in most cases, the `do.call` structure is cleaner and easier than using `parse`, and there's always a risk that parsing a string can cause accidental undesired splitting of arguments.

Comment: I agree that `do.call` is cleaner in most cases. But here, as the arguments (i.e., R expression) are provided as a string, probably `parse` is cleaner. So it think it's on a case by case basis.

Comment: what about the case when the number of arguments in the string is unknown?

Comment: strsplit is not that smart, what if `ylim=c(4,4), xlim=1:2` is passed?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a third answer that both uses `parse`, `alist` and `do.call`. My motivation for this new answer, is in the case where arguments are passed interactively from a client-side as chars. Then I guess, there is no good way around not using `parse`.  Suggested solution with `strsplit`, cannot understand the context whether a comma `,` means next argument or next argument within an argument. `strsplit` does not understand context as `strsplit` is not a parser.

here arguments can be passed as `"a=c(2,4), b=3,5"` or `list("c(a=(2,4)","b=3","5")`

```
#' convert and evaluate a list of char args to a list of arguments
#'
#' @param listOfCharArgs a list of chars 
#'
#' @return
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' myCharArgs = list('x=c(1:3,NA)',"trim=0","TRUE")
#' myArgs = callMeMaybe(myCharArgs)
#' do.call(mean,myArgs)
callMeMaybe2 = function(listOfCharArgs) {
  CharArgs = unlist(listOfCharArgs)
  if(is.null(CharArgs)) return(alist())
    .out = eval(parse(text = paste0("alist(",
      paste(parse(text=CharArgs),collapse = ","),")")))
}

myCharArgs = list('x=c(1:3,NA)',"trim=0","TRUE")
myArgs = callMeMaybe2(myCharArgs)
do.call(mean,myArgs)
 [1] 2
```

Comment: my first answer was fairly unsafe, as a user could have e.g. "quit('no')" or what not evaluated

Answer (score 1):

Using all of `do.call`, `eval` and `parse` (combining kohske's and csgillespie's answers, and also [WoDoSc's answer to 'Pass a comma separated string as a list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036689/pass-a-comma-separated-string-as-a-list)):

```r
x <- c(1:10)
myoptions <- "trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE"

do.call(
  what = mean,
  args = append(list(x = x), eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", myoptions, ")"))))
)
```

This solution can be quite resilient in a more complex case, such as shown below.

```r
myfn <- function(x, y = 0, z = 0, ...) {
  print(paste("x:", x))
  print(paste("y:", y))
  print(paste("z:", z))
  if (length(list(...)) > 0) {
    print("other:")
    print(list(...))
  }
}

myextraargs <- paste(
  "y = c(11, 14), z = 47,",
  "t = data.frame(p = c('apple', 'plum'), j = c(7, 2), k = c(3, 21))"
)

do.call(
  what = myfn,
  args = append(
    list(x = 7),
    eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", myextraargs, ")")))
  )
)
```

results in:

```
[1] "x: 7"
[1] "y: 11" "y: 14"
[1] "z: 47"
[1] "other:"
$t
      p j  k
1 apple 7  3
2  plum 2 21
```

...and...

```r
myextraargs <- NULL

do.call(
  what = myfn,
  args = append(
    list(x = 7),
    eval(parse(text = paste0("list(", myextraargs, ")")))
  )
)
```

results in

```
[1] "x: 7"
[1] "y: 0"
[1] "z: 0"
```