# filter_ with string argument

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

This works (so nice in Shiny):

```
filter_(mtcars, "mpg > 24")
```

and this:

```
filter_(mtcars, "mpg > 24", "disp > 75")
```

Is there a way to make this work as well?

```
filter_(mtcars, "mpg > 24, disp > 75")
```

This works as an alternative

```
filter_(mtcars, "mpg > 24 & disp > 75")
```

**Edit 1**

This works but is there a better way?

```
filter_(mtcars,unlist(strsplit("mpg > 24, disp > 75", ",")))
```

**EDIT 2**

The previous edit may not work as expected. It is equivalent to the following:

```
filter_(mtcars,c("mpg > 24", "disp > 75"))
```

Where the 2nd condition is ignored

```
  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
  1 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.0  1  0    4    2
  2 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.20 19.5  1  1    4    1
  3 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.61 18.5  1  1    4    2
  4 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.83 19.9  1  1    4    1
  5 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.94 18.9  1  1    4    1
  6 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.14 16.7  0  1    5    2
  7 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.51 16.9  1  1    5    2
```

Comment: The alternative (`&`) is way better IMHO. More general too as you can use other operators like `|` for example.

Comment: How about `filter_(mtcars, c("mpg > 24", "disp > 75"))`? What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: You are probably right @flodel but I would like to have the option that input is in 'standard' dplyr notation

Comment: In a locally run Shiny app users can input conditions to filter the data. (&) works fine but a user that knows dplyr may try "mpg > 25 , disp > 75". See my edit about using c(). Doesn't seem to give the same result

Comment: Try `do.call(filter_, c(list(mtcars),unlist(strsplit("mpg > 24, disp > 75", ","))))`. I cannot test as you did not provide a reproducible example.

Comment: That seems to work. Thanks @flodel! Just out of curiosity, why is using mtcars not a reproducible example? It is a default R dataset isn't it?

Comment: I can't find `filter_` although I tried loading `shiny` and `dplyr`. Maybe my versions are too old, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Didn't think about that. I'm using dplyr 0.3.0.2. filter_ was added pretty recently I believe

Comment: FWIW try `filter_(mtcars, .dots = c("mpg > 24", "disp > 75"))`

Comment: Given how the input arrive from the user it would be: filter_(mtcars, .dots = unlist(strsplit("mpg > 24, disp > 75", ","))) correct?

Answer (score 0):

So my assumption here is that you are getting the filtering parameters from a `textInput` so they come through as text. Here is a way that works:

```
library(dplyr)
Args<-c("mpg>24, disp>75")
eval( parse( text=paste("filter(mtcars,",Args,")")    ))

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
2 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
3 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
4 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
5 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
6 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

So in this case `Args` is the input from the user. I used paste to put together a complete `filter` function as a text string. Finally the `eval(parse (..))` bit just evaluates the string as if it were a normal function. Note that this uses `filter` instead of `filter_`

This answer is based on the accepted answer to this question:

[Use character string as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836972/use-character-string-as-function-argument)

Comment: Thanks for the input John. I have used this approach with 'subset' before. Works fine but I am trying to cut-down on my intake of eval-parse. When run on a server I assume that the security risks of hadley's or flodel's approach are lower in comparison

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I'm going to throw out the (perhaps trivial) solution of using `gsub` to replace commas with ampersands in the string:

```
filter_(mtcars, gsub(',', '&', "mpg > 24, disp > 75"))

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
2 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
3 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
4 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
5 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
6 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

This generates the same output you'd expect if you entered that condition into `filter` as a bare expression, works just fine if there are no commas or if the user chooses to use `&`, and doesn't introduce involve the potential risks of using `eval` on arbitrary expressions.