# Use character String as function argument R

Tags: r, string, function, arguments, character

I lost already so much time but I don't get it.

Is it possible to use a String as an argument in a function?

My String is definded as:

```
mergesetting <- "all = FALSE"
```

(Sometimes I use "all.y = TRUE" or "all.x = TRUE" instead)

I tried to set that String as an argument into the following Function:

```
merged = merge.data.frame(x = DataframeA ,y = DataframeB ,by = "date_new", mergesetting )
```

But i get an error message: Error in fix.by(by.x, x)

The function does work if I use the argument directly:

```
merged = merge.data.frame(x = DataframeA,y = DataframeB,by = "date_new", all = FALSE )
```

As well two other approaches found on [Use character string as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836972/use-character-string-as-function-argument)
didn't work:

```
  L<- list(x = DataframeA,y = DataframeB,by = "date_new", mergesetting)
  merged <- do.call(merge.data.frame, L)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use character string as function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836972/use-character-string-as-function-argument)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the point but, 
if you had a list with your data and arguments

Say dfA is this data frame
`kable(head(dfA))
|dates      | datum|
|:----------|-----:|
|2010-05-11 |  1130|
|2010-05-12 |  1558|
|2010-05-13 |  1126|
|2010-05-14 |   131|
|2010-05-15 |  2223|
|2010-05-16 |  4005|`

and dfB is this...

`kable(head(dfB))
|dates      | datum|
|:----------|-----:|
|2010-05-11 |  3256|
|2010-05-12 |    50|
|2010-05-13 |  2280|
|2010-05-14 |  4981|
|2010-05-15 |  2117|
|2010-05-16 |   791|`

Your pre set list:

`arg.li <- list(dfA = dfA,dfB = dfB,all = T,by = 'dates')`

The wrapper for the list function...

`f <- function(x)do.call('merge.data.frame',list(x = x$dfA,y = x$dfB,all = x$all))`

results in:

`kable(summary(f(arg.li)))
|   |    dates          |    datum    |
|:--|:------------------|:------------|
|   |Min.   :2010-05-11 |Min.   :  24 |
|   |1st Qu.:2010-09-03 |1st Qu.:1288 |
|   |Median :2010-12-28 |Median :2520 |
|   |Mean   :2011-01-09 |Mean   :2536 |
|   |3rd Qu.:2011-04-22 |3rd Qu.:3785 |
|   |Max.   :2011-12-01 |Max.   :5000 |`