# How can I pass character strings as independent parameters after a `+`?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

Before you mark as dup, I know about [Use character string as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836972/use-character-string-as-function-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1), but my use case is slightly different. I don't need to pass a parameter INSIDE the function, I would like to pass a dynamic number of parameters after a `+` (think `ggplot2`).

(Note: Please don't format and remove the extra-looking ####, I have left them in so people can copy paste the code into R for simplicity).

This has been my process:

#### So let's reproduce this example:

```
library(condformat)
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   rule_fill_discrete(Species) +
   rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width)
```

[image]

#### I would like to be able to pass the two `rule_fill_discrete()` functions dynamically (in my real use-case I have a variable number of possible inputs and it's not possible to hardcode these in).

#### First, create a function to generalize:

```
PlotSeries <- function(x){
   b=NULL
   for (i in 1:length(x)){
     a <- paste('rule_fill_discrete(',x[i],')',sep="")
     b <- paste(paste(b,a,sep="+")) 
     }
   b <- gsub("^\\+","",b)
   eval(parse(text = b))
 }
```

#### Which works with one argument

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   PlotSeries("Species")
```

#### But not if we pass two arguments:

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   PlotSeries(c("Species","Petal.Width"))
```

> Error in rule_fill_discrete(Species) + rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

#### It will work if we call each individually

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   PlotSeries("Species") +
   PlotSeries("Petal.Width")
```

#### Which gives us an indication as to what the problem is... the fact that it doesn't like when the `rule_fill_discrete` statements are passed in as **one** statement. Let's test this:

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   eval(rule_fill_discrete(Species) +
          rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width) )
```

> Error in rule_fill_discrete(Species) + rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

#### Fails. But:

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) +
   eval(rule_fill_discrete(Species)) +
   eval(rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width) )
```

#### This works. But we **need** to be able to pass in a GROUP of statements (that's kinda the whole point). So let's try to get the eval statements in:

```
Nasty <- "eval(rule_fill_discrete(Species)) eval(rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width))"

 condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) + Nasty                   #### FAIL
```

> Error in `+.default`(condformat(iris[c(1:5, 70:75, 120:125), ]), Nasty) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) + eval(Nasty)             #### FAIL
```

> Error in `+.default`(condformat(iris[c(1:5, 70:75, 120:125), ]), eval(Nasty)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) + parse(text=Nasty)       #### FAIL
```

> Error in `+.default`(condformat(iris[c(1:5, 70:75, 120:125), ]), parse(text = Nasty)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) + eval(parse(text=Nasty)) #### FAIL
```

> Error in eval(rule_fill_discrete(Species)) + eval(rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width)) : 
>     non-numeric argument to binary operator

So how can we do it?

Comment: I find that question using the word "dynamic" are generally very unclear. The word has so many different possible meanings. It's better to make a simple example and say what the inputs and outputs should be. At this point we have the inputs, but then the desired outputs are either not there or so mixed in with the various error messages that I at least cannot find a proper description of the desired output. Trying to mix macro style processing with quoted `"eval"`'s seems far too convoluted.

Comment: Sorry 42, let me try to clarify. I'm STARTING from the desired output... I would just like to create a function that allows me to pass any number of conditional format statements to condformat

Comment: I think I figured out what you wanted to do, but after looking at the conventions used by the `condformat` package, I decided the confusing mixture of standard and nonstandard evaluation were too much for me. I'm not convinced that tagging as ggplot2 is really "honest". I don't think the `+` operator has the same evaluation mechanism.

Comment: Not certain, but the `purrr` package's map functions might help.

Comment: Yes bungo, thank you. See my elaboration on Gregor's excellent answer... it uses a purrr function to apply a slightly more complicated use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer provides a workaround for a bug in an old version of `condformat`. The bug has since been fixed, see @zeehio's answer for the current version after this bug was fixed.

---

I think you have two mostly separate questions. That are all mixed together in your post. I will attempt to restate and answer them individually, and then put things together - which doesn't work all the way at this point but gets close.

First, let's save some typing by defining a couple variables:

```
ir = iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125), ]
cf = condformat(ir)
```

#### Q1: *How do I use `+` on a vector or list of inputs?*

This is the easy question. The `base` answer is `Reduce`. The following are all equivalent:

```
10 + 1 + 2 + 5 
"+"("+"("+"(10, 1), 2), 5)
Reduce("+", c(1, 2, 5), init = 10))
```

More pertinent to your case, we can do this to replicate your desired output:

```
fills = list(rule_fill_discrete(Species), rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width))
res = Reduce(f = "+", x = fills, init = cf)
res
```

#### Q2: *How do I use string inputs with `rule_fill_discrete`?*

This is my first time using `condformat`, but it looks to be written in the `lazyeval` paradigm with `rule_fill_discrete_` as a standard-evaluating counterpart to the non-standard-evaluating `rule_fill_discrete`. This example is even given in `?rule_fill_discrete`, but **it doesn't work as expected**

```
cf + rule_fill_discrete_(columns = "Species")
# bad: Species column colored entirely red, not colored by species
# possibly a bug? At the very least misleading documentation...

cf + rule_fill_discrete_(columns = "Species", expression = expression(Species))
# bad: works as expected, but still uses an unquoted Species

# other failed attempts
cf + rule_fill_discrete_(columns = "Species", expression = expression("Species"))
cf + rule_fill_discrete_(columns = "Species", expression = "Species")
# bad: single color still single color column
```

There is also an `env` environment argument in the SE function, but I had no luck with that either. Maybe someone with more `lazyeval`/expression experience can point out something I'm overlooking or doing wrong.

**Work-around:** What we can do is pass the column directly. This works because we're not doing any fancy functions of the column, just using it's values directly to determine the coloring:

```
cf + rule_fill_discrete_(columns = c("Species"), expression = ir[["Species"]])
# hacky, but it works
```

#### Putting it together

Using the NSE version with `Reduce` is easy:

```
fills = list(rule_fill_discrete(Species), rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width))
res = Reduce(f = "+", x = fills, init = cf)
res
# works!
```

Using SE with input strings, we can use the hacky workaround.

```
input = c("Species", "Petal.Width")
fills_ = lapply(input, function(x) rule_fill_discrete_(x, expression = ir[[x]]))
res_ = Reduce(f = "+", x = fills_, init = cf)
res_
# works!
```

And this, of course, you could wrap up into a custom function that takes a data frame and a string vector of column names as input.

Comment: See my answer for an elaboration on this that worked for my slightly more complex use-case.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in how condformat deals with standard evaluation. I will look into it as soon as I can.  rule_fill_discrete_("Species") should work

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to this stackoverflow question and thanks to the bug report from @amit-kohli, I was made aware that there was a bug in the condformat package.

**Update**: Answer updated to reflect the new condformat API introduced in condformat 0.7.

Here I show how to (using condformat 0.7.0). Note that the syntax I use in the standard evaluation function is derived from the rlang package.

Install condformat:

```
install.packages("condformat)"
```

### A simple example, asked in the question:

```
# Reproduce the example
library(condformat)
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) %>%
   rule_fill_discrete(Species) %>%
   rule_fill_discrete(Petal.Width) 

# With variables:
col1 <- rlang::quo(Species)
col2 <- rlang::quo(Petal.Width)
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(!! col1) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(!! col2)

# Or even with character strings to give the column names:
col1 <- "Species"
col2 <- "Petal.Width"

condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(!! col1) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(!! col2) 

# Do it programmatically (In a function)
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
some_color <- function(data, col1, col2) {
  condformat::condformat(data) %>%
    condformat::rule_fill_discrete(!! col1) %>%
    condformat::rule_fill_discrete(!! col2)
}
some_color(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),], "Species", "Petal.Width")
```

### A more general example, using an expression:

```
# General example, using an expression:
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) %>% 
  rule_fill_gradient(Species, expression = Sepal.Width - Sepal.Length)

# General example, using a column given as character and an
# expression given as character as well:
expr <- rlang::parse_expr("Sepal.Width - Sepal.Length")
condformat(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),]) %>%
  rule_fill_gradient("Species", expression = !! expr)


# General example, in a function, everything given as a character:
two_column_difference <- function(data, col_to_colour, col1, col2)  {
  expr1 <- rlang::parse_expr(col1)
  expr2 <- rlang::parse_expr(col2)
  condformat::condformat(data) %>%
    condformat::rule_fill_gradient(
      !! col_to_colour,
      expression = (!!expr1) - (!!expr2))
}
two_column_difference(iris[c(1:5,70:75, 120:125),],
                      col_to_colour = "Species",
                      col1 = "Sepal.Width",
                      col2 = "Sepal.Length")
```

### Custom discretized scales for continuous values

Custom discrete color values can be specified with a function that preprocesses a continuous column into a discrete scale:

```
discretize <- function(column) {
  sapply(column,
    FUN = function(value) {
      if (value < 4.7) {
        return("low")
      } else if (value < 5.0) {
        return("mid")
      } else {
        return("high")
      }
    })
}
```

And we can specify the colors for each of the levels of the scale using `colours =`:

```
condformat(head(iris)) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(
    "Sepal.Length",
    expression = discretize(Sepal.Length),
    colours = c("low" = "red", "mid" = "yellow", "high" = "green"))
```

If we want, the `discretize` function can return colours:

```
discretize_colours <- function(column) {
  sapply(column,
    FUN = function(value) {
      if (value < 4.7) {
        return("red")
      } else if (value < 5.0) {
        return("yellow")
      } else {
        return("green")
      }
    })
}
```

The code to use it:

```
condformat(head(iris)) %>%
  rule_fill_discrete(
    "Sepal.Length",
    expression = discretize_colours(Sepal.Length),
    colours = identity)
```

Note that as `expression` returns the colours we use `colours = identity`. `identity` is just `function(x) x`.

Finally, using some `rlang` [tidy evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/vignettes/tidy-evaluation.html) we can create a function:

```
colour_based_function <- function(data, col1) {
  col <- rlang::parse_expr(col1)
  condformat::condformat(data) %>%
    condformat::rule_fill_discrete(
      columns = !! col1,
      expression = discretize_colours(!! col),
      colours = identity)
}
colour_based_function(head(iris), "Sepal.Length")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gregor's answer was perfect. A bit hacky, but works excellently.

In my use-case, I needed a bit more complication, I will post it here in case it's useful to somebody else.

In my use-case, I needed to be able to color multiple columns based on the values of one column. condformat allows us to do this already, but again we run into the parametrization problem. Here's my solution to that, based on the response by Gregor:

```
CondFormatForInput <- function(Table,VectorToColor,VectorFromColor) {
        cf <- condformat(Table)
        input = data.frame(Val=VectorToColor,
                           Comp=VectorFromColor)
        fills2_ = map2(input$Val,.y = input$Comp,.f = function(x,y) rule_fill_discrete_(x, expression = 
                                                                                          iris[[y]]))
        res_ = Reduce(f = "+", x = fills2_, init = cf)
        res_
      }

      CondFormatForInput(iris,
                        c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"),
                        c("Sepal.Width","Sepal.Width","Petal.Width","Petal.Width"))
```