# Create a vector of numbers using character string

Tags: r

I spent a lot of time by searching a solution for that, in particular in this answer [Use character string as function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836972/use-character-string-as-function-argument)

Anyway I haven't found a solution.

I would use a string of character as it was my input in the console.

In particular, I can create vector v1 in this way

```
v1 <- c(1, 3, 5:10)
```

[v1]  1  3  5  6  7  8  9 10

I would like to find a way to do this by saving this code `1, 3, 5:10` as an object and than using it as it was my input

`values <- ("1, 3, 5:10")`

`v1 <- c(read.as.input(values))`

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
> a = "1, 3, 5:10"
> b = paste0("c(", a, ")") # paste characters inside c() to parse afterwards
> b
[1] "c(1, 3, 5:10)"
> eval(parse(text = b)) # parse it..
[1]  1  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

As a function:

```
> read.as.input <- function(input_text) {
 +     input_text = paste0("c(", input_text, ")")
 +     result = eval(parse(text = input_text))
 +     return(result)
 + }
> read.as.input("1,3,5:10")
[1]  1  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: yeah, it was exactly this. My problem was that I wasn't able to force **readLine** syntax like "1,3,5:10"  into input to create a vector. Your answer has answered my question! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

We could create a grouping column based on the `diff`erence of adjacent elements, then use that group in `tapply`, to `paste`

```
toString(tapply(v1, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(v1) != 1)), 
   FUN = function(x) if(length(x) > 1) paste(range(x), collapse=":") else x))
#[1] "1, 3, 5:10"
```

---

If it is the other way around

```
values <- c("1, 3, 5:10")
unlist(lapply(strsplit(values, ",\\s*")[[1]],
   function(x) eval(parse(text = x))), use.names = FALSE)
#[1]  1  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: I think the asker wants a solution the other way around: to get `c(1,3,5:10)` from characters

Comment: @ClaudH I am not sure about the format he needs.  In the post, it shows `values <- ("1, 3, 5:10")` as a single string

Answer (score 1):

You can try `eval` + `str2lang`

```
> eval(str2lang(sprintf("c(%s)", values)))
[1]  1  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: This should be the best solution